# Django development server 1.6 did not start at first run

Tags: python, django

Django development server 1.6 did not start at first run with standart config file. What is wrong?

```
December 07, 2013 - 20:21:45
Django version 1.6, using settings 'test_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x028D3DB0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\program_files\python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
 line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
...
...
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 2: invalid
continuation byte
```

Full error listing [here](http://pastebin.com/2aKmCvWP):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a cyrillic symbols in computer name. After renaming and reboot all is ok.